# Java client implementation for NGSI and ContextBroker communications

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

In order to not reinventing the wheel I am looking for some existing library for connecting to Orion Context Broker from Java code.

I have found that at [fiware.org](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Java) there is published sample code but I do not like it as it does not hide raw XML usage.

I have also found some code at [github](https://github.com/UniSurreyIoT/NGSI9/tree/master/src/java/eu/fiware/iot/ngsi)

Some people seems to have [worked on it](https://www.linkedin.com/in/javiercarmonavico) but I did not find the sources.

Is there some open library becoming popular reference on it? being API clean and easy to use and hiding low level things? (XML parsing, NGSI communications, REST, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

We have build a NGSI V1 (**JSON only**) client library for the [Fiware-Cepheus](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/fiware-cepheus) project.

In your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orange.cepheus</groupId>
    <artifactId>cepheus-ngsi</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

In your code :

```java
@Autowired
NgsiClient ngsiClient;
```

...

```java
// Prepare UpdateContext  
UpdateContext updateContext = new UpdateContext(UpdateAction.UPDATE);
ContextElement contextElement = new ContextElement();
contextElement.setEntityId(new EntityId("Room1", "Room", false));
ContextAttribute attr = new ContextAttribute("temp", "double", "20");
contextElement.setContextAttributeList(Collections.singletonList(attr);
updateContext.setContextElements(Collections.singletonList(contextElement));

// Synchronous call
ngsiClient.updateContext("http://broker:port", null, updateContext).get();

// Asynchronous call
ngsiClient.updateContext("http://broker:port", null, updateContext).addCallback(
      updateContextResponse -> { /* success response */ },
      throwable -> { /* error response */ });
```

This library is still under development (available as SNAPSHOT only on the Sonatype repository) and is not considered stable yet, but is fully tested.

It is missing support for many NGSI9 requests, but if your main use is NGSI10, you should be covered.