# Convert Object to NGSI10v1 payload and NGSI10 v1 response to OBJECT?

Tags: json, fiware, fiware-orion

I am looking for solution in Java to convert Object to NGSI10v1 payload (Json) and NGSI10v1 respose(Json) to Object .

Can i do that?
How can i do?

Comment: What do you mean by "Object"? Could you edit your question post to clarify or provide an example, please? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at this node module

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fiware-orion-client

particularly if you have a look at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-SDK/blob/master/Javascript/orion/ngsi-helper.js

source file you will find two useful methods provided by the NgsiHelper object, one for parsing NGSI payloads to JS objects and the other to convert JS objects to NGSI payloads.

best

Comment: Many thanks Jose, but i am looking for the java one. do you have any ideal about this?

Comment: check this article, please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594550/java-client-implementation-for-ngsi-and-contextbroker-communications

Comment: Yep, Thank you so much Jose.